# dsPIC33 Flashing with BIN file

Tags: pic, flash

Noob question here.  I'm new to Microchip devices

I have a dsPIC33 series chip and a PICKit2 programmer.

I have a BIN file I would like to flash the chip with but not sure how to go about it.

The MPLAB IDE and PICKet2 software will load HEX files but they don't seem to recognize BIN files.  Both MPLAB and PICKit2 recognize the dsPIC33 chip when connected to the appropriate pins.

I don't have a HEX or source code of the BIN file.  Just have a BIN file.

Comment: Where did the file come from? MPLAB can import .cof, .cod and .elf files, your file might be one of those. Otherwise, you will probably need the source code.

Comment: What format is the BIN file in?  Is it a flat binary image or something else.  What produced it?  The normal tools will produce a HEX file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MPLAB C30 comes with a utility "mplab-bin2hex" which is used to convert *elf* and *coff* files into *hex* format.  *elf* and *coff* are two types of binary file that the mplab toolchain can create, and both must be converted to *hex* to upload with the pickit2.  If you're in Linux that is located in /opt/microchip/mplabc30/[version]/bin.  If you are in Windows, I have no idea where it is.